# Want to stop countdown and give out put as time up

Tags: php, javascript

Hello i want when my countdown end it should give out as:

```
document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = "Time up";
```

Live countdown here : http://ffsng.deewayz.in/counter/

As its about to end i want to give out put that "Time up"

i tried some thing this way but dint work out.

```
function setCountDown() {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
    }
    if (minutes < 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes = 59;
    }
    if (hours < 0) {
        days--;
        hours = 23;
    }
    document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds";
    if ((seconds = 0) && (minutes = 0) && (hours = 0) && (days = 0))(
        document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = "time up";
    ) else ( 
        setTimeout("setCountDown()", 1000);
    );  
}
```

My full codes is here : [Countdown timer not working with gmt time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594438/countdown-timer-not-working-with-gmt-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty well, but for your needs ok!

**HTML**

```
<div id="countdown">
    <span id="row1"></span><br />
    <span id="row2"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var end = new Date('October 08, 2012 00:55:00');

function toSt1(n) {
    var s = '';
    if (n < 10) s += '0';
    return (s + n).toString();
}

function toSt2(n) {
    var s = '';
    if (n < 10) s += '00';
    else if (n < 100) s += '0';
    return (s + n).toString();
}

var countdown = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var count = Math.floor(end.getTime() - d.getTime());
    if (count > 0) {
        var miliseconds = toSt2(count % 1000);
        count = Math.floor(count / 1000);
        var seconds = toSt1(count % 60);
        count = Math.floor(count / 60);
        var minutes = toSt1(count % 60);
        count = Math.floor(count / 60);
        var hours = toSt1(count % 24);
        count = Math.floor(count / 24);
        var days = count;
        document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML = days + ' Days';
        document.getElementById('row2').innerHTML = hours + ' Hours ' + minutes + ' Minutes ' + seconds + ' Seconds ';
        setTimeout('countdown()', 100);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time up";
    }
}
countdown();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UPPtC/)**

Comment: yes better i can modify it now, yes it will work fine for my case

Answer (score 1):

See this code to do something (give output, as you asked) on complete of countdown:

```
$(function(){
  var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      $('#remain').html('Time up');
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

This solution uses jQuery.

Ref.  [How can I make a jQuery countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown)

Comment: I want to add in my count down... well i will use jQuery next time

Comment: @user1477388 pretty much simpler and prettier and without bloating jquery ;-) https://gist.github.com/3728681